# Implementing Passport Local Authentication in Backend

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js, mean-stack, passport-local

I am trying to implement the passport local authentication in my backend. It is a todo app which is built with the help of the MEAN stack. Unfortunately, I am facing some problems implementing it. The folder structure is

1. In Controllers folder, the controllers for the various routes are present.
2. In routes folder, the file "api.route.js" contains the main route. I want to implement authentication here such that no further routes can be accessed if the user is not autheticated.
3. In the api subfolder, the different routes are configured.
4. In the config subfolder, the passport local strategy is defined.

Another new problem I have noticed is that the routes after todo are not detected.

Example :  localhost:3000/api/todos

```
       localhost :3000/api/todos/login
```

route does not work. It says Error 404. Every other sub routes are the same. Any help which will help me to implement will be appreciated. The github profile for this project is :
https://github.com/AritraWork97/TODO-FULLSTACK

The main folder is Todo Backend, it contains the backend code

Answer (score 0):

To, protect routes in back-end I think [express-jwt](https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt) will be handy.
Initialize it like this,

```
const jwt = require("express-jwt");
const auth = jwt({secret: jwt_secret});
```

Then put the auth middleware before a route that you want to protect.

```
router.get("/secret/:uid", auth, profileCtrl.secret);
```